# Wpf DataGrid with datepicker

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datepicker

How can i access the selected date from datepicker column from the selected row of the wpf datagrid in code behind if i know the datagrid's selected row as

DataRowView drv = datagrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

where datagrid is my datagrid's name.

Comment: which event handler do you get yuur DataRowView from?

Answer (score 0):

If you bind you datagrid to data, then you can access the selected value on your data object.

Comment: Yeah, i can access a column by using drv["ColumnBindingPath"], but here the column contains a datepicker control in it.User can choose some date and then i need to access it. Is it possible to access in the same manner as drv["columnName"]?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the column name then you can get value using

```
drv["columnName"]
```